# Stepper driver reverse polarity

Tags: driver

I would like to use a [MKS TB6600 4.5A](http://reprap.org/wiki/MKS_TB6600) drivers together with an E-cut break out board to drive Nema 23 stepper motors (3A).
My problem is that I cannot figure out how to connect the drivers to the board. Before I fry both the BOB and the driver I would like to ask for some help.

On the driver I see there are four connections: EN, DIR, CLK, GND.

[image]

On the BoB electrical diagram I see they have used a different type of driver. The break out board has 3 connections for the driver: XD ( think is the DIR on the driver), XP (I thinks the CLK on the driver) but then I have +5V and not the GND. I will not use the Enable.

[image]

I am tempted to connect the driver to the board as following:
[image]

but I am not sure if this will work or cause the board or the driver to burn.

Some advice is be appreciated.

Comment: Follow specs . These are just logic levels for Enable, Step pulse (clk) and Direction.    The pulse is normally high with 1us negative edge control (AFAIK)

Comment: It appears to be 5V logic , no pullup needed.  Not very good documentation linked here, yet widely used

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, thanks for your comment but the driver has GND and the BOB has +5V. I do not see how to connect them together without pulp resistors.

Comment: Powerup and measure input V and see if it already has pull-up R, then you will know for sure.  It should be negative logic signals to gnd.  When you load input to 2.5V with R to gnd , then you can know the exact R pull-up value.